# What are texlive-fonts-extra and texlive-latex-extra-doc used for?

Tags: texlive

1. In my installed texlive 2009-15 on Ubuntu, I have these two
   packages:

   ```
   217.684 MB   texlive-fonts-extra
   249.281 MB   texlive-latex-extra-doc
   ```
2. What are all packages with `doc` in their names used for? Are they not necessary? When I need to figure out how to use Latex, I always consult the internet, so can I safely remove all "doc" packages?

   ```
   0.672 MB     texlive-doc-th
   1.215 MB     texlive-doc-nl
   1.445 MB     texlive-doc-ja
   1.645 MB     texlive-doc-ko
   1.895 MB     texlive-doc-tr
   1.984 MB     texlive-doc-base
   2.004 MB     texlive-doc-si
   2.301 MB     texlive-doc-fi
   2.402 MB     texlive-doc-cs+sk
   2.441 MB     texlive-doc-mn
   2.645 MB     texlive-doc-uk
   2.656 MB     texlive-doc-bg
   3.009 MB     texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
   3.727 MB     texlive-doc-es
   3.953 MB     texlive-doc-it
   4.266 MB     texlive-doc-vi
   4.980 MB     texlive-doc-ru
   6.090 MB     texlive-doc-pt
   7.469 MB     texlive-doc-de
   8.289 MB     texlive-doc-pl
   8.918 MB     texlive-doc-zh
   9.027 MB     texlive-doc-fr
   11.138 MB    texlive-metapost-doc
   11.273 MB    texlive-humanities-doc
   12.930 MB    texlive-science-doc
   16.547 MB    texlive-pictures-doc
   19.738 MB    texlive-latex-recommended-doc
   30.680 MB    texlive-fonts-extra-doc
   43.855 MB    texlive-publishers-doc
   59.125 MB    texlive-latex-base-doc
   67.484 MB    texlive-pstricks-doc
   90.848 MB    texlive-doc-en
   249.281 MB   texlive-latex-extra-doc
   ```

I want to free up some space. So I would like to know what they are used for, so that I can decide if I can remove them.

Thanks.

Comment: They provide you a lot of new fonts, new symbols and the documentation for them. I don't recommend you to remove if you use TeX a lot. Also, less than 500mb would change enough to you?

Comment: Thanks. Are all packages with doc in their names not necessary? When I need to figure out how to use Latex, I always consult the internet, so can I safely remove all "doc" packages?

Comment: There is an advantage in having documentation which you know automatically concerns the versions of packages you have installed. Since you are using Ubuntu's TeX Live, the versions of manuals on CTAN will sometimes be for newer versions of packages and this can make a significant difference to how those packages can be used. Will saving 500MB really make that much difference? You *could* remove `texlive-doc-xy` for all `xy` language codes which you cannot read in any case e.g. if you can't read Russian, there's no point in having the Russian documentation.

Comment: Texlive 2009!? A lot has happened since 2009.

Comment: @cfr: Both being small, to me a free 500Mb (on an SSD) is more important than the difference between the installed and the latest version of a latex package, yes. Especially if it's a fonts package (as compared to say, tikz). I'm gonna google/SE the doc AND update my distribution anyway, if I have to debug anything. So I understand it makes sense to default-install them, but to anyone looking to free space, I think the helpful advice is "**just remove it**". Currently, just `texlive-fontsextra` is >1000Mb on my machine, in a 12-occupied-Gb `/` partition.